# Users can edit AD groups in Windows Explorer "Active Directory Search"

Tags: active-directory

I have a question about the windows explorer "active directory search" feature.

A active directory user (member of the domain users group) found out, that when he uses the active directory search, he can edit the domain admins group and add himself as a member.

Does anyone know where I can restrict this?

Thank you

Kind regards

Comment: There's a difference between adding himself to the group and committing the change. Have you verified he is successful in adding himself to the group? If so, you have a very big permission/delegation problem that needs to be sorted out immediately. Please let us know.

Comment: Hello m-admin, were you able to identify the root cause for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Examine the group members of "Domain Admins" or "Enterprise Admins" to see if any group he is a member of, is also a member of those groups.